# Transition edge attributes from bipartite to one mode graphs

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I'd like to adopt an edge attribute from a bipartite graph for the one mode graph that is the result of command `bipartite_projection`.

```
library(igraph)

data <- data.frame( people= c(letters[1:5],letters[5:8],"a"),
             events=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
             year=c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data)
V(g)$type <-  V(g)$name %in% data[,1] # Nodes are the people 
E(g)$year                             # this is what I want
proj <- bipartite.projection(g)

g2 <- proj[[2]]
```

Problems start here

```
E(g2)$year                       # here it is gone

el <- get.edgelist(g2)
el <- cbind(el, E(g)$year)    # ideally add it here to the edgelist
```

Does anyone know how to keep this edge attribute or how to index it properly, so that one can access it later on? Thanks in advance!

Edit for clarification (thanks @Heikki and @dllhell for your edit suggestion):

The idea behind this is to get the edgelist from a temporal network. The nodes are the people and the edges are the events. The events take place in certain years. To know which people met at the same event in the same year, I use the `bipartite_projection`.

Maybe this awfully edited picture helps:

[image]

So as you can see the edges are basically the events but unfortunately the information about the year goes missing. 
Maybe this clears things up.

Thanks for your help so far :-)

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly, but if you just want to add the value to that list you can do it like this `list.append(el, E(g)$year)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not quite, it would be better if I had the format of an edgelist with three columns and not one long list.

Comment: Should the years be matched with the first column in `el` or to the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, try and let me know if it works:

```
library(igraph)

data <- data.frame( people= c(letters[1:5],letters[5:8],"a"),
                    events=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                    year=c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data)
V(g)$type <-  V(g)$name %in% data[,1] # Nodes are the people 
data$year_2 <- E(g)$year                             # this is what I want
proj <- bipartite.projection(g)

g2 <- proj[[2]]

E(g2)$year                       # here it is gone

el <- get.edgelist(g2)

el <- as.data.frame(el)

colnames(el)[1] <- "people"
el <- merge(el,data$year_2)
```

**EDIT**

**Explanation**
The solution that I have found is to:

1. Convert `el` into a `dataframe`
2. Create new data frames (`event1` and `event2`) for each of the events
3. Create a new variable (`year`) in the `el` dataframe and use `ifelse` statements to assign the right value to that variable.

This is specific to a two events scenario but it can be easily extended. If you don't know the number of events you will get, you can just use a loop.

**Code**

```
library(igraph)

data <- data.frame( people= c(letters[1:5],letters[5:8],"a"),
                    events=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                    year=c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data)
V(g)$type <-  V(g)$name %in% data[,1] # Nodes are the people 
 E(g)$year                             # this is what I want
proj <- bipartite.projection(g)

g2 <- proj[[2]]

E(g2)$year                       # here it is gone

el <- get.edgelist(g2)

el <- as.data.frame(el)


event1 <- subset(data, events == 1)
event2 <- subset(data, events == 2)
el$year <- 0
el$year <- ifelse(el$V1 %in% event1$people & el$V2 %in% event1$people,  unique(event1$year), el$year )
el$year <-ifelse(el$V1 %in% event2$people & el$V2 %in% event2$people,unique(event2$year), el$year)
```

Comment: Thanks once more. This sadly not what I intend to accomplish. This way I would match every possible combination. I updated my post, maybe this helps, sorry for being imprecise.

Comment: @BenNutzer Thanks, now it's clear! Will try to find a better way

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. This is a solid solution. I'll have to see how it translates into the bigger dataset (with a lot more events and years) but it's a most usefull approach :-)